# Why $k/m$ in simple Harmonic motion equal $\omega^2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I've come across this thing in simple harmonic motion but never did I manage to find a reason why $k/m$ should equal $\omega^2$ and the theory behind it. People say it is done for convenience equating dimensional but no actual reason did I find.

Comment: Solve the harmonic oscillator. The solutions involve sines and cosines of frequency $\sqrt{k/m}$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You'll find the analysis of the simple harmonic oscillator in any introductory physics book.

Answer (score 2):

This is only from intuitive meaning.

Let us find the mathematical meaning of $k/m$ .
Here, the equation is 
$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{k}{m}x$

suppose $\frac{k}{m}=K$
Then, the solution of this equation is 
$x=A\sin{\sqrt{K}t}$
quantity inside the sine function is the angle. Thus, $\sqrt{K}$ must be angular velocity. 
Thus, $$\sqrt{K}=\omega\\  
K=\omega^2$$.
 And this is why we substitute $\frac{k}{m}=\omega^2$